# How to build a multipage ReactJs Shopping Cart

Tags: jquery, reactjs

This is bit general question , I am building a website

[**LINK**](http://mad.ideleads.com)

The website is built on Laravel which is a PHP framework.

In this I want to add a shopping cart Based on ReactJS any suggestion how to go forward with this.

So basically I would Like to build a

> BUY NOW

button on clicking on which I can take the `ID, name and cost` of the product and add it to the shopping cart.

And this cart should work on all the pages of the website .

I am really new to ReactJs and have fair knowledge of Jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Look into something like Redux, Reflux or Flux, for keeping the data in stores. Since the stores are on the client-side only, they need to be rehydrated if the user decides to refresh the page. You can either store the products in the local-storage of the browser, or handled by your php backend

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use some some storage on client side (cookie (bad idea), localStorage (nice)). You must store SC data here. Also you can store all SC data on server side and return it with all responses (but it's bad idea).
2. You need to use ReactRouter (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) to create SPA.
3. I think you can write SC module and add it to your base template.